# How can I filter my coordinates system?

Tags: c#, design, c++, algorithms

Following up with [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400410/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-coordinate-with-respect-to-mouse-position), I have a bunch of coordinates and I draw them on a bitmap image as a coordinate system. Now, I would like to get rid of all the noise, and filter coordinates to give a "clearer" or "cleaner" path and "less" or "better" data to work on. To explain more, I will need to expose my **awesome** *painting* skills as follows:

**Current:**

[image]

**Desired:**

[image]

Notice:

- I might need to delete coordinates
- I might need to add coordinates
- I might need to ignore shortest neighbor in some cases

The only thing I can think of, is to use a shortest path algorithm such as [**A***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) and [**Dijkstra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). And populate data in some sort of data structure to contain neighbors and costs for every node and then to execute the algorithm. I don't want to start something that might be wrong or waste. I would love to see a pseudo code if possible on **how could I solve such a problem**?

P.S I am currently on Wpf C# but I am open to use C# or C++ for any task. Thanks

Comment: You're probably looking for [*curve fitting.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks! Please allow me sometime to research it

Comment: Your description is lacking in detail. There are many cases I can imagine where it is no obvious what result should be? What if there are two groups that are separated by large empty space? What if the group is roughly circular?

Comment: Do those samples arrive in any particular order? Are they sampled at some interval? Or is that all of the information that you receive? Can you possibly get a time-stamp for each sample?

Comment: [Also posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38513619/781723).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W I think I learned my lesson after this issue I had. I never done that though. Now I couldn't delete because it has an answer. What should I do? Please and thanks

Comment: At this point there's nothing you can do; the moderators are the only ones who can do anything further.  This is more for others who run across this question, so they don't waste their time answering a question that's already received multiple good answers.

Comment: I see @D.W. Maybe I should have edited my question to mention that I found a solution. Sorry about that. And thanks again

Comment: No, don't edit the question to say you've found a solution.  For future information, the right solution is to post only one copy, and indicate you've found a solution by accepting one of the answers.  No worries, you don't need to do anything further at this point.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Look in my profile for the same Q but on Stack Overflow, the answer is there

Comment: @KyleKhalaf This question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400410/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-coordinate-with-respect-to-mouse-position

Comment: @DanielMårtensson No. Look for the same exact Q, same date as well

Comment: @KyleKhalaf I assume that Q = question?

Comment: @KyleKhalaf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513619/how-can-i-get-thinner-graph-for-my-coordinate-system Here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have little mathematical background but I do see an approach that might work.

I would assign a value to each coordinate in the grid that is determined by the amount and closeness of dotted neighbors. Then apply a threshold: only keep the coordinates that exceed the threshold value. Those will form the result path.

Comment: Hi Martin and thanks. So I need to go to every node, and calculate its distance from ALL other nodes, and then choose a threshold to calculate a _Value_ that represents this node with respect to "some neighborhood". And then, base my filtering on the value of every node, ignore nodes that have a value above some other certain threshold?

Comment: You would check every coordinate in the area of interest (not just the ones that have nodes) and look around for nodes to calculate the "crowdiness factor". This could result in an empty point in between several nodes to get a higher value which is what you want, you want a path through the crowdiest parts of the coordinate system.

Comment: You will have to fiddle with the algorithm  to calculate the crowdiness, it would incorporate distance and numbers and closer nodes would get the value up more but how far you want to look around and how quick the significance of nearby nodes should degrade with distance depends on scale and distribution of your nodes.